# Mapping nested x-form-urlencoded data to DTO in Asp.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dto

Implementing a webhook in Asp.Net Core which is POSTed to with `application/x-form-urlencoded` data - it's receiving data in a format that is designed to be easily processable in PHP w/ the `$_POST` variable (nested associative array) - the form fields look like

```
foo
bar[barf]
baz[bat][bark]
baz[bat][bant]
```

Is there a nice (elegant and little code required) way to wire up the Asp.NET Core model binding to handle the nested structure here? i.e. when the webhook gets POSTed to, we parse a C# POCO -

something like

```cs
class RootDto {
    public string Foo {get; set;}

    public Bar Bar {get; set;}
    public Baz Baz {get; set;}

    public class Bar {
        public string Barf {get; set;}
    }

    public class Baz {
        public Bat Bat {get; set;}

        public class Bat {
            public string Bark {get; set;}
            public string Bant {get; set;}
        }
    }
}
```

The POST body looks something like the following:

```
foo=somevalue&bar%5Bbarf%5D=anothervalue&baz%5Bbat%5D%5Bbark%5D=123.0&baz%5Bbat%5D%5Bbant%5D=5000
```

i.e.

`foo=somevalue&bar[barf]=anothervalue&baz[bat][bark]=123.0&baz[bat][bant]=5000`

Also, what's the low-friction way to set up a type-converter for one of these fields (e.g. assume the field "Foo" comes in as a string but we want to parse it into a struct)?

Note that I don't have control of the shape or encoding of the data coming in from the webhook (e.g. I can't request they just send me JSON).

Comment: can you give an example of the raw incoming data you need to deserialize? This might be useful for capturing it https://webhook.site

Comment: Have added sample data.

Comment: Decorating the properties with `[FromForm(Name = "foo")]` means the DTO property names can differ from the POST data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Request body

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=somevalue&bar%5Bbarf%5D=anothervalue&baz%5Bbat%5D%5Bbark%5D=123.0&baz%5Bbat%5D%5Bbant%5D=5000
```

It just works.... I have plain .net core project and controller looks like

```
  public IActionResult Post([FromForm] RootDto request)
        {
            return Ok(request);
        }
```

[image]

Btw your root class seems to be wrong I've changed to make it work

```
public class RootDto {
    public string Foo {get; set;}

    public BarClass Bar {get; set;}
    public BazClass Baz {get; set;}

    public class BarClass {
        public string Barf {get; set;}
    }

    public class BazClass {
        public BatClass Bat {get; set;}

        public class BatClass {
            public string Bark {get; set;}
            public string Bant {get; set;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to change how the shape/encoding of the incoming request, see edit to my post for sample data I need to map to a DTO.

Comment: wow - impressive! What if we want the property names on the DTO to differ from what is used in the request?